# How can I format json in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have this Json. I want to use in AngularJs but I need modify this before. I tried to use foreach and reordering the objects but the final result is not enought good.

```
$scope.data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        company: "MOVISTAR",
        option: "PRECIO"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        company: "MOVISTAR",
        option: "CALIDAD"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        company: "MOVISTAR",
        option: "TECNOLOGIA"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        company: "CLARO",       
        option: "PRECIO"
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        company: "CLARO",       
        option: "CALIDAD"
    };
```

I need format like this

```
$scope.datax = [

        {
            empresa: "MOVISTAR",
            description:[{
                id: 1,
                opcionResp: "PRECIO"
                },
                {
                id: 2,
                opcionResp: "CALIDAD"
                },
                {
                id: 3,
                opcionResp: "TECNOLOGIA"
                }]
        },
        {
            empresa: "CLARO",
            description:[{
                id: 4,
                opcionResp: "PRECIO"
                },
                {
                id: 5,
                opcionResp: "CALIDAD"
                }]
        }];
```

I don't have much experience with json and angular. Help me please.

Thanks so much

Comment: You'll probably want to take the time to learn JavaScript before diving into Angular. Here is a video on how to iterate through an array https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-the-array-foreach-method . You'll need to use that to construct your "formatted" object

Comment: I can't think of any way through which you can convert the the JSON format. But why do you want to convert it to the other format? Angular will easily work with the format you have. You don't "NEED" to modify it.

Comment: Hi @someonenew . I've tried to make this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/D33ZECyE2dGOc6nynsQT?p=preview. It's the reason because I need format the Json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Formatting json** can be done by calling

```
angular.toJson(myObject)
```

To convert `$scope.data` to your desired structure, you can iterate `$scope.data` and build a new object as the following:

**Online Demo - https://plnkr.co/edit/TFW38xWKhMxmTdf11vbQ?p=preview**

```
function fixData(data) {

    var cache = {};
    var results = [];

    data.forEach(function(item) {
      var values = cache[item.company];

      if (!values) {
        values = [];

        results.push({
          empresa: item.company,
          description: values
        });

      }

      cache[item.company] = values;

      values.push({
        id: item.id,
        opcionResp: item.option
      })

    });

    return results;
}
```

see online demo - https://plnkr.co/edit/TFW38xWKhMxmTdf11vbQ?p=preview

Comment: Thanks mate @jossefharush . It's I need

Answer (score 1):

It´s quite simple with forEach:

```
var cache = {};

$scope.data.forEach(function(o){
  (cache[o.company] = (cache[o.company] || [])).push({id:o.id, opcionResp:o.option}) 
})

$scope.datax = Object.keys(cache).map(function(key){
    return {empresa:key,description:cache[key]}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First find all distinct companies, then go through the original data for each company and load up your description array:

```
        $scope.datax = []

        for (var i in $scope.data) {
            if (distinct.indexOf($scope.data[i].company) == -1) {
                $scope.datax.push({
                    empresa: $scope.data[i].company,
                    description: []
                })
            }
        }

        for (var j in $scope.datax) {
            for (var k in $scope.data) {
                if ($scope.datax[j].empresa == $scope.data[k].company) {
                    $scope.datax[j].description.push({
                        id: $scope.data[k].id,
                        opcionResp: $scope.data[k].option
                    })
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Always a pleasure @capitanjack